# Mapbox rotate map based on user bearing

Tags: android, mapbox

I am writing a navigation app and I require rotation of the camera around the user (So rather than just rotating the user icon with the compass the camera rotates around the user giving the impression that the map is rotating in accordance to real life.)

I couldn't seem to find a default mode to do this I have tried the bearing tracking modes (GPS and Compass) as well as the location tracking modes:

```
mapboxMap.getTrackingSettings().setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW);
```

As I was unable to get it working I implemented a custom compass with a basic low pass filter in order to rotate the camera around the user. However as of upgrading from Mapbox 4.1.1 to 4.2.1 my custom implementation has broken (Rotation has become very laggy and very jagged).

I am sure there is a much easier way to do this but I am having a bit of trouble figuring it out. Could someone please advise me as to whether I was going about it the correct way or if there is a much easier solution that I am looking over?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To track the user location and rotate the map to the orientation is always pointing in the same direction as the user, use these lines combined:

```
mapboxMap.getTrackingSettings().setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW);

mapboxMap.getTrackingSettings().setMyBearingTrackingMode(MyBearingTracking.COMPASS);
```

Note for the full code, i'd recommend checking out [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/location/LocationTrackingActivity.java).

Comment: Thanks. Just as a note, in my case, this line made all of the difference:

`map.getTrackingSettings().setDismissAllTrackingOnGesture(false);`

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement same structure. But I'm getting my location from external library. Any way to accomplish user tracking without `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` this line. For some reasons, I don't want Mapbox custom `myLocation` pointer on map. Any help, please?

Comment: The example link is broken; how do we do this now? It appears that the code was deprecated by/replaced with the LocationLayer plugin, but it doesn't appear to have a `FOLLOW` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @SCTaylor says, you absolutely need `.setDismissAllTrackingOnGesture(false)` to make this work